# Change KDE kickoff slide effect speed

Tags: kde, kubuntu, animations

How can I change or increase the KDE kickoff slide effect speed?

I don't mean when moving from one tab to another (Favourites to Applications, for instance) - I mean from menu to submenu (so clicking on "Internet" to reveal a list of internet-oriented applications, like a web browser, IM client etc.).

I find the default sliding speed to be just slightly too choppy and slow and pretty irksome (especially when the rest of the KDE desktop is so smooth).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the animation speed from the "System settings" application. Open up the [K] menu, select "System settings" (or type systemsettings and press enter). In the application, select "Desktop effects". This configuration page has an "Animation speed" setting, where you can choose everything from reaally, painstakingly slow, to "instant".

As an added bonus, on the "All effects" tab in this configuration window, there is a checkbox for "Sliding popups". If you cannot find an animation setting that works for you, you could try turning off the sliding animation altogether by disabling that particular effect (uncheck the box for "Sliding popups").

Comment: also some other effects int he all effects tab replace the slide. Mine glides in.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the speed. At least the current release of KDE (4.5) doesn't support changing it.

Future releases of KDE might support changing the animation speed.